# Array to String Conversion Error (shows up on production server)

Tags: laravel

I have a DB query which is fetching data and retrieving it as a collection when I "dd" it. The same is stored into a variable and this variable is passed to the view. On running a "foreach" on this variable, I'm trying to access the variable data using "->" in the view page.

When I'm running it on the localhost, there is no issue. But when I try to run the same on the server, "Array to String Conversion" occurs for some users while for others it doesn't.

The error doesn't look like a coding error either since it is random in its nature. Once I clear the cache and cookies of the chrome of the person receiving the error, it disappears.

Since removing cache all the time isn't a feasible solution, could someone explain why this error keeps popping up intermittently.

/* Code in the controller */

```
$leaddata=DB::table('leads')
->select('services.*','personneldetails.*','addresses.*','leads.*')
->join('personneldetails', 'leads.id', '=', 'personneldetails.Leadid')
->join('addresses', 'leads.id', '=', 'addresses.leadid')
->join('services', 'leads.id', '=', 'services.LeadId')
->where('leads.id','=',$id)
->where('serviceType',$servicetypeinurl)
->orderBy('leads.id', 'DESC')
->get();
```

/* Blade code snippet */

```
@foreach ($leaddata as $lead)

    <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 7px;">
        <a href="{{'/Verticalhead/'.$lead->id.'/edit?servicetype='.$lead->ServiceType.'&requestedservice='.$lead->requested_service.'&url='.$url}}"  class="editt" style="float: right;"><img src="/img/edit.png" class="img-responsive" alt="oops! Not found"> </a>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

Image for the error

https://ibb.co/cVXaVJ

Note - It doesn't look like a code error to me because on clearing the cache it vanishes. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Please paste the result of dd($leaddata->toArray()) here.

Comment: i think `$lead->ServiceType` should be `$lead->serviceType` because in where condition you have `serviceType`

Comment: typo in code : `ServiceType` to `serviceType`

Comment: This is how the dd($leaddata) looks.

https://imgur.com/a/2t9ijEZ

Comment: That typo doesn't seem to be giving any error. This query has been working wonderfully for the past 7 months. Only during this release has the error started showing up.